# How to remove infinity values from a tensor in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

Say I have a tensor as following :

```
var = tf.constant([0,0.05,0.2,0,0])
inverse_var = tf.math.reciprocal(var)
print(inverse_var)

Output :  tf.Tensor([inf, 20. , 5. ,inf inf], shape=(5,), dtype=float32)
```

**I want to make a new tensor from inverse_var tensor such that the infinity values are replaced with zero in the new tensor.**
**Final vector required - [ 0, 20, 5, 0, 0 ]**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution done using [tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensor_scatter_nd_update) method

```
import tensorflow as tf
var = tf.constant([0,0.05,0.2,0,0])
inverse_var = tf.math.reciprocal(var)
print(inverse_var)
mask = tf.math.is_inf(inverse_var)
indices = tf.where(mask) # found indices where infinite values are 
print(indices)
updates=tf.zeros(len(indices)) # create 1D matrix of length of infinite values
inverse_var_inf = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(inverse_var,indices,updates) #updated using scatter_nd_update method
print(inverse_var_inf)
```

Thank you!
providing [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/4bf99fe4a69d2695571042ee69a70373/stack_68418846.ipynb#scrollTo=bwqAifDhmq9w) for reference